# ResolveInfo.loadIcon() causes warning-Spam

Tags: android

In my android application, I am displaying a list of every user-app installed.

Everything runs fine, but as mentioned in below code, calling `icon = info.loadIcon(context.getPackageManager());` results in two annoying warnings. Since I am loading every app on the device, this generates a huge list of warnings that are spamming my console.

Despite the warnings, the icon is loading and displaying fine.

I don't really get where this warning comes from. How to debug it? Alternatively, can one disable Log-Output of a specific code line?

Here is my wrapper class:

```
public class AppWrapper {
    public final Drawable icon;
    public final String appLabel;
    public final String packageName;

    public AppWrapper(Context context, ResolveInfo info) {

        //Warnings are produced here:
        icon = info.loadIcon(context.getPackageManager());
        /*
         PackageManager: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
         ResourceType: Failure retrieving resources for com.example.app: Resource ID #0x0
         */

        appLabel = info.loadLabel(context.getPackageManager()).toString();
        packageName = info.activityInfo.packageName;
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This really should not implement Serializable. Drawables are stateful.

Comment: You are right. Actually i removed it in the current code. Edit was made to the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
icon = info.loadIcon(context.getPackageManager());
```

instead

```
icon = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName);
```